# What did Cate Blanchett say?

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation

https://youtu.be/m_ZVJgM-bZI?t=16

> This year, five actors lifted the __________ of expectations (...)

What exactly did Cate Blanchett say? I'm going to assume it's a loanword or something.

Comment: ..*lifted the lid of expectations*.. the actor initially mispeaks but self corrects herself.

Comment: Ohhhh she was self correcting herself lol, "lifted the eight the lid".

Comment: I think she started to say "lifted the expectations,  but only got as far as lifted the ek the lid of expectations. I.e. she initially missed out the words "lid of"